# Help me to get command or ansibile Regex to fetch below details

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, ansible

My data:

```
KVM05786Y: The Communication host "ADMK05786HTREDIRECT_JA3A" is SUCESS
KVM05786Y: The Communication host "KOPYUTRCEPORT_JA3A" is SUCESS
KVM05786Y: The Communication host "ADMK05786HTSRM_JA3A" is SUCESS
KVM05786Y: The Communication host "ADMK05786HTIAS_JA3A" is SUCESS
KVM05786Y: The Communication host "ADMK05786HTOTN_JA3A" is SUCESS
KVM05786Y: The Communication host "ADMK05786HTWPM" is SUCESS
KVM05786Y: The Communication host "OCAIDEKD_JA3A" is SUCESS
KVM05786Y: The Communication host "ADMK05786HTSC_JA3A" is SUCESS
```

From the above data, I want to display only the names below. This means taking the text that is found after `host` and before `is`. Please give me a Linux command that can do this.

```
ADMK05786HTREDIRECT_JA3A
KOPYUTRCEPORT_JA3A
ADMK05786HTSRM_JA3A
ADMK05786HTIAS_JA3A
ADMK05786HTOTN_JA3A
ADMK05786HTWPM
OCAIDEKD_JA3A
ADMK05786HTSC_JA3A
```

I tried this in ansible:

```
name: "Get data"
shell: cat /var/tmp/http_data.txt
register: key_data
set_fact:
service_name: "{{ service_name | default([]) + [item|regex_search( 'The Communication host\s+"(\S+)"\s+is SUCESS.*','\1' )] }}"

with_items: "{{ key_data.stdout_lines }}"
```

Comment: How can we know what lines to print? Do you want whatever is inside `" "` on every line? Or do you want the 5th word of every line? Do you only want it if the last word is `SUCCESS`? Do you only want lines matching those _specific_ strings you gave? Please [edit] your question and explain how we can identify the lines you want.

Comment: I want only the data which is after 'host' and before 'is' word, none of the below commands working,

Comment: Then please ***[EDIT]*** your question, as we have asked so this information is included. The reason none of the answers works for you is that you have not explained what you need. So people are trying to guess.

Comment: Also, please don't revert edits that fix your post! You can use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your post so that code is clearly shown.

Answer (score 1):

A few different approaches:

1. Select whatever is between `host "` and `" is`:

   ```
   $ sed -En 's/.*host "([^"]*)" is.*/\1/p' file
   ADMK05786HTREDIRECT_JA3A
   KOPYUTRCEPORT_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTSRM_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTIAS_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTOTN_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTWPM
   OCAIDEKD_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTSC_JA3A
   ```

   or, using `grep` with perl compatible regular expressions (`-P`) which support [lookarounds](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

   ```
   $ grep -oP '(?<=host ").+?(?=" is )' file
   ADMK05786HTREDIRECT_JA3A
   KOPYUTRCEPORT_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTSRM_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTIAS_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTOTN_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTWPM
   OCAIDEKD_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTSC_JA3A
   ```
2. Using the position in the line; we assume that you always want the 5th space-separated field:

   ```
   $ awk '{print $5}' file | tr -d '"'
   ADMK05786HTREDIRECT_JA3A
   KOPYUTRCEPORT_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTSRM_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTIAS_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTOTN_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTWPM
   OCAIDEKD_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTSC_JA3A
   ```

   or, removing the quotes in `awk`:

   ```
   $ awk '{gsub(/"/,""); print $5}' file 
   ADMK05786HTREDIRECT_JA3A
   KOPYUTRCEPORT_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTSRM_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTIAS_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTOTN_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTWPM
   OCAIDEKD_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTSC_JA3A
   ```
3. Simply print all quoted strings on each line

   ```
   $ grep -oP '"\K[^"]+(?=")' file
   ADMK05786HTREDIRECT_JA3A
   KOPYUTRCEPORT_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTSRM_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTIAS_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTOTN_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTWPM
   OCAIDEKD_JA3A
   ADMK05786HTSC_JA3A
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot terdon, the 2nd option worked for me, thanks again,  similarly can you help me to get in powershell command to execute in windows server?

Comment: @Ramesh no, sorry. Windows is off topic here, I have never used powershell and I don't have any idea what would be needed. You could try asking on [su] instead. Also, if one of these answers sovled your issue, please take a moment to [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -o '"[^"]\+"'
```

This will return the info between the double quotes.  There are definitely more robust ways to do this but if data is always in that format it will work and even if names change it will work.

Comment: Note that this will also include the quotes. To avoid that, you could try: `grep -oP '"\K[^"]+(?=")'` or `grep -oP '(?<=")[^"]+(?=")'`.

Comment: this is my variable values/content, from this i want to grep or extract only data  which is after 'host' and before 'is', this did not work for me grep -oP '(?<=")[^"]+(?=")' {{ variable }}

KVM05786Y: The Communication host "ADMK05786HEDIRECT_JA3A" is SUCESS<br>
KVM05786Y: The Communication host "KOPYUTRCEORT_JA3A" is SUCESS<br>
KVM05786Y: The Communication host "ADMK05786HSRM_J3A" is SUCESS<br>
KVM05786Y:  Communication host "ADMK0576H_JA3A" is SUCESS<br>
KVM05786Y: The Communication host "ADMK05786_JA3A" is SUCESS<br/>
KVM05786Y: Communication host "OCAIDEKD_JA3A" is SUCESS<br/>

Comment: `grep -o '"[^"]\+"' | sed 's/“//g'`

Comment: @Ramesh When asked for clarifications, please don't respond in comments, but edit your post to include the requested information. Reading through the comments is rather painful, and comments are subject to removal without notice by moderators.

Comment: Or use my original if you want to keep quotes.

Comment: I think you meant to write `grep -o '"[^"]\+"' | sed 's/"//g'` in your previous comment. The fancy quotes (`“`) wouldn't work.

Comment: @Ramesh the other advantage to [editing your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/636418/edit) to add clarifications is that it gets put on the review queue for reopening